# Sorting and replace object key value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a payload looking like this:

```
{ key: 1 }
```

How can I actually replace this payload to something like below?

```
{ "key.something": { anotherKey: "abc" } }
```

My old code to replace the payload looks something like this.

```
let a = { ...payload };

if (lodash.isEqual(a, { key: 1 })) {
  a = {
    "key.something": { anotherKey: "abc" }
};

return a;
```

But I think the current method I'm using is just not effective enough because there's just too many ifs later on. So how can I actually get the key value and then sort it based on the key value and then replace it just like above?

Thanks for the help

Comment: what are you trying to solve? 
if the payload key is equal to 1, 
return `{"key.something": { anotherKey: "abc" }}`?   

if that's the case `if(payload.key === 1)  return {"key.something": { anotherKey: "abc" }};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the values based on the payload, just make a 2d array containing the value you want to replace and the replace value and loop over it

```js
let a = {... payload};

let combinations = [
    [{key: 1}, { "key.something": { anotherKey: "abc" } }],
    // some more combinations
];

combinations.forEach(e => {
    if (lodash.isEqual(a, e[0])) {
        a = e[1];
        break;
    }
})

return a;
```

Comment: Okayy, but what if I only have 1 object payload, is it necessary to do a looping?

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I have misunderstood the question, but if the payload has a `key` equal to `1` return (replace) the payload with

```js
{ "key.something": { anotherKey: "abc" } }
```

#### Updated based on comment

If so, you could simply do the following:

```js
function transformPayload(payload, searchKey, searchVal){
   if(payload[searchKey]){
     if(payload[searchKey] === searchVal){
       return {
           'key.something': { anotherKey: "abc" }
       }
     }
   }
   else throw new Error(`payload does not have the key: ${searchKey}`);
}
```

Then invoke this function:

```js
const updatedPayload = transformPayload(payload, 'key', 1);
```

Comment: Ah yess I know I can just replace it like that, but in my case the key name here could be different like sometimes it's `{ aKey: 0 }` or `{ bKey: 1 }`. That's why if I use if statements there will be too many ifs :(

Comment: @Hasimy I have updated the answer accordingly. You can use a dynamic key like so: `const checkKey = (key, val) =>  payload[key] === val;` then `checkKey('aKey', 1); checkKey('bKey', 1);`